# Error - Index exceeds matrix dimensions

Tags: matlab, runtime-error

I have the following portion:

```
N = size(p,1);
x = 1:N; y = x;
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
R = sqrt((2.*X-N-1).^2+(2.*Y-N-1).^2)/N;
Theta = atan2((N-1-2.*Y+2),(2.*X-N+1-2));
R = (R<=1).*R;
Rad = radialpoly(R,n,m);    

Product = p(x,y).*Rad.*exp(-1i*m*Theta);
```

I get the error in the following line:

```
Product = p(x,y).*Rad.*exp(-1i*m*Theta);
```

The error that I get is:

```
Index exceeds matrix dimensions.
```

I tried to "debug" the program, and found that the dimensions issue may be due to the following line:

[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);

The weird thing is that the program doesn't give me errors on most of the images I'm applying it on.

Do you know why I'm getting such error?

Thanks.

Comment: What is `p` and `radialpoly`? Right now, we don't have enough information to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Likely, the issue is not due to meshgrid. Are you sure your p is always a square image (i.e. you use y=x, but get N only from the first dimension of p)

Comment: btw, shouldn't you access `p` using `y,x` instead of `x,y`? i.e., row-column indexing rather than XY coordinates?

Comment: Was Kostya suggested: what happens for an image `p` of size 100x200?

Comment: `p` is an image, but, not a square image

Answer (score 0):

first of all, it would be nice to see how you assign your `p` variable.

to make sure that you the `size(y)==size(p)` try

```
assert(size(p,1) == size(p,2) )
```

or

```
assert(N == size(p,2) )
```

if it returns an error, then your `p` is not square.

---

if you know beforehand that you have a rectangular (non-square) array, assign your `y` correspondingly:

```
x = 1:size(p, 1)
y = 1:size(p, 2)
...
%// and maybe dependent on what you do:
N = min(size(p))
```

this will make sure it does not exceed size of `p` when indexing it along the second dimension

Comment: `p`is an image. And, yes, it is not a square. What should I do in the code I have shown to remove the issue of the square image. And, by the way, when the width of the image is larger than its height, I don't get any error]